# Volume Control while Screen Off with proximity sensor

Tags: android, screen, sensors, proximity

In Android, is there a way to be able to change volume through volume tracker up/down when screen is turned off through proximity sensor?

Answer (score 0):

Android Proximity sensor have only two value for sense. NEAR & FAR. just returns 1.0 or 0.0. value.
and make question clear what exactly you want to do.